# Unity 2D Raycast refection is not working Properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am want to create reflection trajectory using line renderer using 2d physics.
The refection is not working properly some times it works some times it not.
for 3d everything is working fine if just replace vector2 with vecor3 and use 3d physic function.

Maybe it's related to the collider or else I am added box collider 2d on the colored blocks.

I wrote his code

```
void GenerateRay(Vector2 position , Vector2 direction , int count){

    if(count==0) return;

    Vector2 oldPosition = position;

    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(position , direction , maxRayLenght);

    if(hit.collider!=null){

        direction = Vector2.Reflect(direction , hit.normal);
       print(direction);
        position = hit.point;
         print(position);

    }
    else
    {
        position += direction*maxRayLenght;
    }


    lineRenderInstance[maxHop-count].SetPosition(0 , oldPosition);
    lineRenderInstance[maxHop-count].SetPosition(1 , position);



    GenerateRay(position , direction , count-1 );
}
```

if I change the y distance the reflection works sometime and sometimes not.[!

Non working case

[image]

Working case if change the height
[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with your `maxRayLenght`?

Comment: @Dave increasing ray length also doesn't work.

Comment: please show how are your sprites setup in inspector and code where you call the `GenerateRay`.

Comment: @Dave I am calling this function in update. I have added the sprite setup image.

Comment: Try running your code in `FixedUpdate`

Comment: Still not working.